# jQuery live with time picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

To show `.timePickr` I need to do *double hover* and move mouse to another place before I see the `.timePiker` box when I use `live` event.

How can me make it by one hover ?

```
$(".timePickr").live('hover', function() {
    $(function(){
        $(".timePickr").timepickr();
    });
});
```

Comment: no it's hard.. and I fix it thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're adding the timepicker to the input *after* the hover event has been fired. The timepicker won't be shown until the next time you hover.

There are two options. Either you trigger the hover event again:

```
$(function() {
  $(".timePickr").live('hover', function() {
    $(this).timepickr();
    $(this).hover();
  });
});
```

A better option is to move the code to apply the time picker in the document load function, or whenever you dynamically introduce new elements.

```
$(function() {
  $(".timePickr").timepickr();
});

//Somewhere else
$.get("someurl", null, function(data) {
  $("#some-div").html(data);
  $(".timePickr").timepickr();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$(function() {
   $(".timePickr").timePickr(); // set all timePicker on document load

   $(".timePickr").live('hover', function() {
       $(this).trigger('click');
   }); 
});
```